# Firebase on Android suddenly not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This person has a similar issue to me [Firebase for android not working in my test device suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194637/firebase-for-android-not-working-in-my-test-device-suddenly) but it was never answered, and the people in the comments seem to have a similar issue.

I can access (and update) values in my firebase using nodejs but when I try to do it from android, there are no failures in logcat or anything, it just does not update anything in the database.

I checked the database reference and it's exactly the same as in my nodejs script, and my security settings are `read: true`, `write: true`... It just doesn't make sense why it's not working anymore. The exact same code was working fine yesterday.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: nothing showing up on the firebase-debug log?

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code + config that reproduces the problem, it'll be hard to help. You might want to enable debug logging to see if that show more in logcat: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.enableLogging

Comment: thanks guys, it turns out it was DNS issues on the device. weird there was no log output for the fetch/write failures though. not even the databse failure clauses were called.

Comment: @Zuhayr looks like I'm having the same issue - how did you fix the DNS issue?

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 5):

After spending HOURS on this myself - the revolutionary solution is to quit the emulator and reopen it again / restart your device.

Comment: In my case I disabled IPv6 in my router.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it would work on an emulator but not on a real device. It turns out I had to reset my WiFi router. This answer helped me: [Firebase database listeners don't work on android with wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340327/firebase-database-listeners-dont-work-on-android-with-wifi)

Comment: In my case I disabled IPv6 in my router.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue. Looked almost all the blogs,even contacted firebase support as well but couldn't find the solution. Finally here is the solution.
Just update your existing **google-services.json** from Firebase->Your project's **Project Settings**.
Rebuild the app and try it out!

Answer (score -1):

Remove firebase from your android project and then again connect it Properly!

1. Delete the project from firebase.com, it will delete the API keys from google cloud console.
2. Delete the implementations from build.gradle just remove each line containing firebase word.
3. Remove the GoogleServices.json file.
4. Remove the plugins from the build.gradle at the beginning.

Now invalidate caches and restart.
clean the project.
And with a fresh start connect the app with firebase and then things should work properly.

Mine was not working because I mistakenly deleted the keys from google cloud and then things became worse. I was unable to undo the step cause I am not an experienced developer.

CHECK THIS ANSWER ALSO - [Firebase credentials API deleted mistakenly not working after creating api manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63240641/firebase-credentials-api-deleted-mistakenly-not-working-after-creating-api-manua)