# Firebase credentials API deleted mistakenly not working after creating api manually

Tags: android, firebase

Suddenly my application started throwing an error here:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "errors": [{
            "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "badRequest"
        }],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

I successfully solved that problem

Then I created a signed apk from the android studio and then I got an error again which is due to the sha1 fingerprint was not in the firebase. I also solved that problem successfully.

But...
Suddenly my application is not working like I can't sign in and there are no red lines in the console. I don't know the reasons. My app is completed but at the last moment the sign-in is not working like it does not call on failureListener but it does not call succeed also.

I already did these things.

1. Matched the firebase google services JSON file with the file in my project (Completely same).
2. Checked the API's from google cloud console and they are matching properly (completely same).
3. Checked the build.Gradle file the implementations are proper.
4. Checked the android manifest file and the project id's and other things are the same as in the firebase JSON file and in the firebase settings.
5. The google cloud console has one API autogenerated by firebase.
6. The google could console has 2 o auth client id's created by me using the sha1 fingerPrints for both debug and release.
7. Also Invalidated and restarted the IDE.
8. Also checked on other devices.
9. Also, checked with different internet connections.

My project is too big to move to another android project and I don't want other problems, they may occur if I do mistake while moving the files.

Firebase Assistant is saying Connections exists for storage, analytics, crashlytics, and more...
Here are the lastest console reports from the android studio when I click the button to sign in button.

```
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 14026
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1888755682
D/PhoneWindow: DEBUG_ALIENSCREEN:getRotation mRotation=0
I/DecorView: setWindowBackground mBackgroundPadding = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), mFramePadding = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), pkg = com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@1bf912d[]
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@1bf912d[SignInHubActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@cc54b61
D/ViewRootImpl[SignInHubActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{9759c4f com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity,ident = 3}, this = DecorView@1bf912d[SignInHubActivity]
I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onAttached
E/: nFreeSize: 32784990208
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x77b8df7000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x77b8df7000)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1888755756
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77bc0a9580) (w:720 h:1436 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
D/SurfaceExt: ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
    Surface::connect(this=0x77b8dfe000,api=2)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77b93cbb40) (w:1 h:1 s:32 f:0x1 u:933)
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
D/SurfaceExt: ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
    Surface::connect(this=0x77b8df8000,api=2)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77b93cbb40) (w:720 h:84 s:736 f:0x1 u:933)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77bc0a9a00) (w:720 h:1436 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
    ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
E/: nFreeSize: 32784990208
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77b93cbb40) (w:1 h:1 s:32 f:0x1 u:933)
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
D/SurfaceExt: ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x77b93cbb40) (w:720 h:84 s:736 f:0x1 u:933)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 75
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1888755837
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
E/: nFreeSize: 32784986112
E/: nFreeSize: 32784977920
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1888757941
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{b04e448 com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary/com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary.BackupRestore,ident = 1}, this = DecorView@a36c565[BackupRestore]
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x77b8df7000,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77bc0a7e40) (w:720 h:1436 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77bc0a8200) (w:720 h:1436 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
    ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
D/SurfaceExt: callingApp: com.example.lifejournalpersonaldiary
D/SurfaceExt: ENABLE_WHITE_LIST: false,isInWhiteList: false
D/Surface: lockCanvas
I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onDetached
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@1bf912d[SignInHubActivity]
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x77b8df8000,api=2)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77b8ca5140) (w:720 h:84 s:736 f:0x1 u:933)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77ba3c1040) (w:720 h:84 s:736 f:0x1 u:933)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x77b8dfe000,api=2)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77cd4e1d80) (w:1 h:1 s:32 f:0x1 u:933)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x77ba3c1100) (w:1 h:1 s:32 f:0x1 u:933)
D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: DecorView@1bf912d[SignInHubActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@cc54b61
E/: nFreeSize: 32784973824
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step - 1. The solution is to remove firebase dependencies from the project and then invalidating caches and then clean Project. Restart android studio.

Step - 2. You have to remove some lines from Gradle files, also from the project setting -> modules -> delete each containing firebase name in it.

Step - 3. After that, remove your project from the firebase and it will show a dangerous warning. After restarting the android studio, connect firebase from the tool menu. Add the plugins that you need in the project like database, storage, auth, crashlytics, etc.

Step - 4. Then add the SHA keys (debug and release both with sha 256 also) again in the project setting of firebase otherwise you will get stuck again.

TIPS: Do not change project name or anything similar because it does not matter and doing so may cause problems. and This time do not delete the API keys from console.cloud.google.com, actually, you should not mess with the API's because we don't need to do that. Firebase automatically creates the keys and works very properly.