# Firebase database listeners don't work on android with wifi

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my code user signs in to Firebase with Google like explained in:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

This works fine.

When a user opens the program, it loads the initialization values from the firebase database. Here is the code:

```
private void loadPrefsFromDB() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = user.getUid();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    userPrefs = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserPrefs.class);
                    updateUI(userPrefs);
                    Log.d(TAG, "loadPrefsFromDB:onDataChange");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "loadPrefsFromDB:onCancelled");
                }
            });
}
```

This works well when the wifi connection is turned off, but if i open the program wifi on, the function does not trigger. If, while the program is running, I click the wifi off and the phone switches to mobile data I instantly get login:

```
D / MainActivity: loadPrefsFromDB: onDataChange
```

The function also gets triggered if I sign out and again in with wifi on.
Shouldn't firebase handle this situation? Or do I need to refresh authentication somehow?

Comment: Show your `updateUI` method and you are not using datasnapshot anywhere, how do you update your UI then

Comment: I updated the code here. I save dataSnapshot and UI is updateing correctly. This is not my problem, but well noticed.

Comment: Ok, so are you talking about wifi connection or internet connection?

Comment: I do not know what prevents updates to the Firebase database or retrieving values when wifi is turned on. Wifi and internet connection is working fine with my devices except when using firebase database.

Comment: try `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: did u solve your problem? I encountered a similar problem. No event firing over wifi (very good connection speed)

Comment: No. I moved to use Firebase messaging. I have not encountered any connection problems with it. My app works in background so this is better solution for me. No need to worry about system killing my service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was struggling with this issue for two days and found the real-time database just cannot work on the specified WIFI, that was my office's WIFI. It can work on the mobile data and even the hotspot signal from other mobile phones. I finally resolved it by restarting the WIFI router in our office, but cannot figure out the behind reason.

Comment: Bit dated, but I'd mark @Freddie's answer as the solution. I was banging my head against this one too. Did the same with my router - I restarted it, and now my app connects to Firebase RTD no problem. I'm wondering how I would let my users know to do this too, in case they have issues connecting for the same reason.

Comment: Crazy, it's 2020 and I am just having this issue. I didn't think to restart the router - but it worked! Thanks for posting. Btw, which router do you have? Mine is D-LINK Model Name: DIR-890L

Comment: In my case I disabled IPv6 in my router.

Comment: Crazy, had the same issue!!! took me hours to understand i is a wifi issue